# Como usar regex correctamente

Tags: python, regex

espero esten bien, la verdad no se si es de principiantes, pero no me familiarizo mucho con el modulo re, y estoy a punto de volverme loco con algo tan simple

Estoy tratando de buscar esta cadena, y el filename varia entre minusculas, mayusculas, digitos, caracteres especiales como %$#_- etc

```
attachments/018/796/036/original/Aleatorio.txt
attachments/118/496/034/original/Test1.txt
attachments/028/196/336/original/Test_1.txt
attachments/028/196/336/original/Test_1_test.txt
```

```
page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, timeout=10)
pattern='(attachments\\/\d{3,}\\/\d{3,}\\/\d{3,}\\/original\\/\w.*.txt?)'
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.I | re.U) 
file = regex.search(page.text)
print(file)
```

Quisiera saber como es la forma para aceptar cualquier carácter en el filename

Comment: ¿Además de probar si la línea encaja en el patrón, quieres obtener también el nombre del fichero? ¿O el nombre de la ruta completa? ¿O sólo saber si la línea encaja?

Comment: Si, necesito obtener  el nombre del fichero

Answer (score 1):

Algunas cosas:

- El carácter `\` dentro de una expresión regular es especial, y se usa para varias cosas, como por ejemplo para indicar que el siguiente que aparezca tras él debe tomarse "literalmente" (es decir, quitar el significado especial de otros caracteres, como por ejemplo en `\.` para indicar que el punto ha de ser literal), o para crear símbolos con un significado concreto, como por ejemplo `\w` que significa "cualquier carácter alfanumérico o guión bajo").
- Pero se da la (desafortunada) circunstancia de que el `\` también tiene un significado especial dentro de una *cadena* en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación, y sirve para cambiar el significado de la letra que aparezca detrás. Un ejemplo típico es `\n` que significa "retorno de carro". En particular, si queremos meter un `\` dentro de un string, sin que tenga significado especial, debemos precederlo de otro `\`, y escribir por tanto `\\`.
- Por culpa de esto último, cuando queremos construir expresiones regulares en las que el `\` es un signo habitual, ya que las tenemos que meter en una cadena, el `\\` debe aparecer duplicado.

En tu expresión regular hay un `\w` al final que debería ser por tanto `\\w`. Aunque pienso que podría sobrar por completo ese `\\w`, pues con él estás forzando a que el nombre de fichero comience por letra, dígito, o guión bajo. Si quieres cualquier carácter inicial como válido, no pongas ese `\\w`.

Además tienes un `.txt?` que debería ser `\\.txt`, para forzar a que el punto sea literal (si no, el punto significa "cualquier caracter"). Y sobra el interrogante final, que en expresiones regulares marca el carácter anterior como "opcional", es decir, que la `t` final podría aparecer o no.

Por otro lado:

- Si abres un paréntesis dentro de una expresión regular estarás dando comienzo a un **grupo de captura**, que finaliza cuando se cierra el paréntesis.
- Los grupos de captura sirven para poder "quedarte" con un trozo de toda la expresión. Por ejemplo, para quedarse con el nombre de fichero como tú quieres.

En tu expresión regular hay un paréntesis al inicio y otro al final, por tanto estás creando un grupo de captura que se queda con "la ruta completa". No es eso lo que querías.

Finalmente:

- Ya que las expresiones regulares abundan en `\`, y las cadenas normales fuerzan a duplicarlos, al final te queda todo lleno de `\\`  y se hacen dificil de leer. Para evitar esto, Python tiene cadenas *raw*, que se marcan poniendo una `r` delante de la cadena, y dentro de las cuales el `\` no tiene significado especial y por tanto no es necesario duplicarlo.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, tu expresión regular sería:

```
pattern = r'attachments\/\d{3,}\/\d{3,}\/\d{3,}\/original\/(.*\.txt)'
```

Observa la `r` delante de las comillas de apertura, para marcar ese string como *raw* y así no tener que duplicar los `\`. He corregido también los problemas antes señalados, y he hecho que el grupo de captura contenga sólo el nombre del fichero.

Al grupo de captura puedes acceder mediante el método `.group()` del objeto resultante del match. Por ejemplo:

```
txt = """
attachments/018/796/036/original/Aleatorio.txt
attachments/118/496/034/original/Test1.txt
attachments/028/196/336/original/Test_1.txt
attachments/028/196/336/original/Test_1_test.txt
"""

for linea in txt.split("\n"):
  r = re.search(regex, linea)
  if r:
    print(r.group(1))
```

producirá como resultado:

```
Aleatorio.txt
Test1.txt
Test_1.txt
Test_1_test.txt
```

**Bonus**. Para practicar con expresiones regulares, probar si funcionarán antes de escribir el programa, y obtener el significado de cada carácter dentro de ellas, es muy útil el sitio [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Por ejemplo puedes practicar con tu caso a partir de [esto](https://regex101.com/r/K5zmeF/1)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración, creo que lo de los (paréntesis) es porque use txt2re.com y me dio la expresion asi, otra cosa, los archivos no se dan por linea, si no que son aleatorios, es decir copio un link, y busco la cadena, copio otro link y busca la cadena etc..

Comment: Me imagino que los nombres de archivo salen de algún sitio, pero para poder poner un ejemplo que cualquiera pueda probar rápidamente, los especifiqué dentro de una cadena. Tienes que adaptarlo a tu caso.

Comment: Opte por usar este regex para obtener los filename, y sin problema (\s*.*\s*)

Comment: Vaya, pues hemos estado perdiendo el tiempo con un problema mal especificado :-(, porque esa expresión regular que dices tan solo extrae cualquier secuencia de caracteres con tal de que haya un espacio al principio y otro al final. Al final ni la ruta  ni la extensión pintaban nada, y tampoco tenías que extraer únicamente el nombre del fichero, como habías dicho, sino la ruta completa.